# verifying a probability distribution with variable arguments sums to 1

Tags: scala

I was wondering how you would write a method in Scala that takes a function `f` and a list of arguments `args` where each arg is a range.  Suppose I have three arguments (`Range(0,2)`, `Range(0,10)`, and `Range(1, 5)`).  Then I want to iterate over `f` with all the possibilities of those three arguments.

```
var sum = 0.0
for (a <- arg(0)) {
  for (b <- arg(1)) {
    for (c <- arg(2)) {
      sum += f(a, b, c)
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want this method to work for functions with a variable number of arguments.  Is this possible?

Edit: is there any way to do this when the function does not take a list, but rather takes a standard parameter list or is curried?

Comment: I think it is possible through recursion, but only if `f` accept list of values.

Comment: I was hoping to solve it without this restriction (`f` takes a standard parameter list or is curried).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a really good question!

You want to run `flatMap` in sequence over a list of elements of arbitrary size. When you don't know how long your list is, you can process it with recursion, or equivalently, with a fold.

```
scala> def sequence[A](lss: List[List[A]]) = lss.foldRight(List(List[A]())) {
     |    (m, n) => for (x <- m; xs <- n) yield x :: xs
     | }
scala> sequence(List(List(1, 2), List(4, 5), List(7)))
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(1, 5, 7), List(2, 4, 7), List(2
, 5, 7))
```

(If you can't figure out the code, don't worry, learn how to use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and [steal it from Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#mapM_))

You can do this with Scalaz (in general it starts with a `F[G[X]]` and returns a `G[F[X]]`, given that the type constructors `G` and `F` have the `Traverse` and `Applicative` capabilities respectively.

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> List(List(1, 2), List(4, 5), List(7)).sequence
res3: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(1, 5, 7), List(2, 4, 7), List(2
, 5, 7))

scala> Seq(some(1), some(2)).sequence
res4: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))

scala> Seq(some(1), none[Int]).sequence
res5: Option[Seq[Int]] = None
```

Comment: Cool answer--I'll definately have to check scalaz out.

Answer (score 1):

That would more or less do the job (without applying f, which you can do separately)

```
  def crossProduct[A](xxs: Seq[A]*) : Seq[Seq[A]] 
    = xxs.foldLeft(Vector(Vector[A]())){(res, xs) => 
      for(r <- res; x <- xs) yield r :+ x
    }
```

You can then just map your function on that. I'm not sure it's a very efficient implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

That's the answer from recursive perspective. Unfortunately, not so short as others.

```
def foo(f: List[Int] => Int, args: Range*) = {
    var sum = 0.0
    def rec(ranges: List[Range], ints: List[Int]): Unit = {
      if (ranges.length > 0)
        for (i <- ranges.head)
          rec(ranges.tail, i :: ints)
      else
        sum += f(ints)
    }
    rec(args.toList, List[Int]())
    sum
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955797/scala-method-to-combine-each-element-of-an-iterable-with-each-element-of-another/5956500#5956500). I use this code for exactly this purpose. It's slightly optimized. I think I could produce a faster version if you need one.