# scala: combining 2 sets of lists

Tags: list, scala, set

I'm trying to write a function that combines 2 sets of lists in Scala. Each list in the second set has to be appended to each list in the first set to get every possible permutation however this does not work as case foo causes an error to appear anybody know how to fix this?

```
  type foo = List[bar]
    def combine(s1:Set[foo],s2:Set[foo]):Set[foo] ={
      s1.map{
        case foo => {s2.foreach{
        case foo=> a.append(b)}}
      }.toSet
    }
```

So largely my problem is in how to refer to a list inside a map function.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: a and b are my attempts to somehow connect the case to the elemt in s1 and s2 but I can't quite see how to connect them so they are left as a and b (part of the problem)

Comment: Sets are iterable, so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955797/scala-method-to-combine-each-element-of-an-iterable-with-each-element-of-another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to append all elements of `s1` with `s2`. The simplest thing would be to:

```
type bar = Int
type foo = List[bar]
def combine(s1:Set[foo], s2:Set[foo]):Set[foo] = for{
x <- s1
y<- s2
} yield x ::: y

val s1 = Set(List(1),List(2))
val s2 = Set(List(3),List(4))
combine(s1,s2)                                 
//> res0: scala.collection.Set[collection.OwnCollection.foo] = Set(List(1, 3), 
                                              //| List(1, 4), List(2, 3), List(2, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use flatMap

```
class Bar
type Foo = List[Bar]
def combine(s1: Set[Foo], s2: Set[Foo]): Set[Foo] = {
  s1.flatMap(a => s2.map(b => a ::: b))
}
```

Note that the syntax for `map` and `flatMap` is of the form `collection.map(x => transform(x))`, so you do not need the `case` keyword here.

An equivalent way, slightly more concise, is to use for comprehension

```
def combine(s1:Set[Foo], s2:Set[Foo]): Set[Foo] = 
  for(a <- s1; b <- s2)
    yield a ::: b
```

For an introduction to sequence comprehension in Scala, you can have a look here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111

Answer (score 0):

doesn't the for comprehension do what you want?

```
for{
  a <- s1
  b <- s2
} yield a.append(b)
```